# Unreachable code after .load_vars() method call

Tags: pyomo

when I call the method `load_vars()` on my `SolutionLoaderBase` object, the following code (any code) becomes unreachable. Is that intended or is it some kind of bug?

For example using CPLEX (but it doesn't really matter which solver I use):

```
self.slvr = appsi.solvers.Cplex()
self.slvr.config.load_solution = False
self.results.solution_loader.load_vars()
...anything next is an unreachable code
```